# Managing DB and Session operations BEFORE login

Tags: session, authentication, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

When a user comes to our webset/webapp, we would like the user to be able to go around the site and do things as normal (currently the site consists of almost exclusively CRUD operations).  That way the user can see what the site has to offer by DOING, before logging in.

We want to store all these operations in a session or temporarily in SQLAlchemy operations but not commited to the database.

Then, we'd like it if when the user creates an account or logs in, all those operations are done under that account name.

What is a good way to do this?  Currently all our server-side functionality automatically does a SQLAlchemy commit after successful database operations.  So I'm not sure if removing that and doing commits manually would be a good idea.

On the other hand, saving database operations in a session/cookie seems bad as well.  Then we need to fake the database in cookies, which is ugly and a lot of work.

Note that we are using postgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to assign a temporary username to every user that visits the site & store that information in a SESSION cookie along with everything else they do while there. Then when they signup, you can move all those SESSION var's into the DB under their new username.

BTW, there's nothing wrong with saving anything in SESSION cookies, as long as you're using HTTPS (and it sounds like you should be using that for the site you've got). Anytime you're doing login stuff over HTTP, it's *never* safe/secure to store anything in cookies.